# How to fit docker in this architecture?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-service-fabric

Fairly new to Docker. Trying to understand how Docker can be used in this real life enterprise level applications.

Here are the components (all hosted in Azure) that make up the website:

- Web services
- Web App
- Azure search
- Document DB
- Web jobs

How can one utilize docker in this scenario?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question that will likely only attract broad answers. Here's one: One docker container (they're service really) per your web service, web app, document db. The Azure search is an external component that you don't need to containerise. The Web jobs, well they will likely be managed by a job queue, which you can also containerise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need Docker at all, that only introduces an extra management overhead. What you have perfectly fits PaaS scenario and Azure gives you much more than you will do with Docker (you'll probably have to spend years trying to get the same functionality).
As you tagged your question with Service Fabric: you won't need that too, although it's a great framework providing lots of microservice based architecture orchestration out of the box. It can utilize Docker to host services (I think on Linux it uses Docker out of the box).
So unless you have a specific problem I wouldn't look in this direction and concentrate on improving your application functionality and quality, existing services already fit best.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main takeaway here is: why do you want docker at all? You don't seem to provide any reason for that. And there's no point in using docker if you don't know why do you want to use it.

But all the services you indicated are PaaS, so introducing docker somewhere here (except for webapps) would only increase your administrative overhead, why do you need that? WebApps can be painlessly converted to docker (WebApps Linux have the ability to launch docker containers, you can even use private repos).

Also, it is not considered a best practice to host your persistent data (Document DB in your case) in containers, it can be done, but a lot of people would argue against that.

ps: this question is mostly opinion based and hence should be closed